# Issue while upgrading my raspberry

Tags: linux, debian, python, raspberry-pi, debian-stretch

My stretch raspberry can't upgrade properly. I've had a lot of issues with Python recently, and this seems to be the bottleneck once again.

## Upgrade the packages

So here what comes when I try to upgrade :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get upgrade
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Vous pouvez lancer « apt --fix-broken install » pour corriger ces problèmes.
Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 idle3 : Dépend: python3 (>= 3.5.3-1) mais 3.4.2-2 est installé
         Dépend: idle-python3.5 mais il n'est pas installé
 libavfilter5 : Dépend: libopencv-core2.4 mais il n'est pas installable
 libopencv-features2d2.4 : Dépend: libopencv-core2.4 mais il n'est pas installable
 libopencv-flann2.4 : Dépend: libopencv-core2.4 (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1+deb8u2) mais il n'est pas installable
 libopencv-highgui2.4 : Dépend: libopencv-core2.4 mais il n'est pas installable
 libopencv-imgproc2.4 : Dépend: libopencv-core2.4 (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1+deb8u2) mais il n'est pas installable
 libopencv-ml2.4 : Dépend: libopencv-core2.4 (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1+deb8u2) mais il n'est pas installable
 libopencv-video2.4 : Dépend: libopencv-core2.4 mais il n'est pas installable
 libreoffice-gtk : Dépend: libreoffice-gtk2 mais il n'est pas installé
                   Dépend: libreoffice-systray mais il n'est pas installé
 python3 : Dépend: python3-minimal (= 3.4.2-2) mais 3.5.3-1 est installé
 python3-apt : Dépend: python3 (>= 3.5~) mais 3.4.2-2 est installé
 python3-cffi : Dépend: python3-cffi-backend (< 1.9.1-2+c) mais il n'est pas installé
                Dépend: python3-cffi-backend (>= 1.9.1-2) mais il n'est pas installé
 python3-cryptography : Dépend: python3-cffi-backend-api-min (<= 9729)
                        Dépend: python3-cffi-backend-api-max (>= 9729)
                        Dépend: python3-idna (>= 2.0) mais il n'est pas installé
                        Dépend: python3-pyasn1 (>= 0.1.8) mais il n'est pas installé
 python3-dbus : Dépend: python3 (>= 3.5~) mais 3.4.2-2 est installé
 python3-dev : Dépend: python3 (= 3.5.3-1) mais 3.4.2-2 est installé
               Dépend: libpython3-dev (= 3.5.3-1) mais 3.4.2-2 est installé
               Dépend: python3.5-dev (>= 3.5.3-1~) mais il n'est pas installé
 python3-gi : Dépend: python3 (>= 3.5~) mais 3.4.2-2 est installé
 python3-markupsafe : Dépend: python3 (>= 3.5~) mais 3.4.2-2 est installé
 python3-numpy : Dépend: python3 (>= 3.5~) mais 3.4.2-2 est installé
 python3-pil : Dépend: python3 (>= 3.5~) mais 3.4.2-2 est installé
               Dépend: libwebp6 (>= 0.5.1) mais il n'est pas installé
               Dépend: libwebpdemux2 (>= 0.5.1) mais il n'est pas installé
               Dépend: libwebpmux2 (>= 0.5.1) mais il n'est pas installé
 python3-tk : Dépend: python3 (>= 3.5) mais 3.4.2-2 est installé
 python3-uno : Dépend: python3 (>= 3.5~) mais 3.4.2-2 est installé
               Dépend: libpython3.5 (>= 3.5.0~b1) mais il n'est pas installé
 sonic-pi : Dépend: libQt5printsupport5 mais il n'est pas installable
E: Dépendances non satisfaites. Essayez « apt --fix-broken install » sans paquet
   (ou indiquez une solution).
```

## Fix-Packages

And here is what comes when I try to fix :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt install -f
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Correction des dépendances... Fait
Les paquets suivants ont été installés automatiquement et ne sont plus nécessaires :
  coinor-libipopt1 libavdevice55 libboost-atomic1.55.0 libboost-filesystem1.55.0 libboost-program-options1.55.0 libboost-regex1.55.0 libboost-thread1.55.0 libchromaprint0 libffi5 libgmime-2.6-0 libgtkglext1 libilmbase6 libkate1
  libmimic0 libmjpegutils-2.1-0 libmms0 libmodplug1 libmpeg2encpp-2.1-0 libmplex2-2.1-0 libmumps-seq-4.10.0 liboauth0 libofa0 libopenexr6 libqt5svg5 libraw10 libruby2.1 libscsynth1 libsoundtouch0 libspandsp2 libsrtp0 libvo-aacenc0
  libvo-amrwbenc0 libwildmidi-config libwildmidi1 libyaml-0-2 libzbar0 ruby ruby2.1 rubygems-integration supercollider-server
Veuillez utiliser « sudo apt autoremove » pour les supprimer.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ffmpeg idle-python3.5 jackd2 libav-tools libavcodec57 libavdevice57 libavfilter6 libavformat57 libavresample3 libavutil55 libchromaprint1 libebur128-1 libjack-jackd2-0 libopencv-core2.4v5 libopencv-imgproc2.4v5 libopenjp2-7
  libopenmpt0 libpgm-5.2-0 libpostproc54 libpython3-dev libpython3-stdlib libpython3.5 libpython3.5-dev libreoffice-gtk2 libreoffice-systray librubberband2 libsdl2-2.0-0 libshine3 libsnappy1v5 libsndio6.1 libsodium18 libsoxr0
  libssh-gcrypt-4 libswresample2 libswscale4 libtwolame0 libva-drm1 libva-x11-1 libvpx4 libwebp6 libwebpdemux2 libwebpmux2 libx264-148 libx265-95 libzmq5 libzvbi-common libzvbi0 python3 python3-cffi-backend python3-idna python3-pyasn1
  python3.5-dev
Paquets suggérés :
  ffmpeg-doc jack-tools meterbridge sndiod python3-doc python3-venv doc-base
Les paquets suivants seront ENLEVÉS :
  libavfilter5 libopencv-features2d2.4 libopencv-flann2.4 libopencv-highgui2.4 libopencv-imgproc2.4 libopencv-ml2.4 libopencv-video2.4 sonic-pi
Les NOUVEAUX paquets suivants seront installés :
  ffmpeg idle-python3.5 libavcodec57 libavdevice57 libavfilter6 libavformat57 libavresample3 libavutil55 libchromaprint1 libebur128-1 libopencv-core2.4v5 libopencv-imgproc2.4v5 libopenjp2-7 libopenmpt0 libpgm-5.2-0 libpostproc54
  libpython3.5 libpython3.5-dev libreoffice-gtk2 libreoffice-systray librubberband2 libsdl2-2.0-0 libshine3 libsnappy1v5 libsndio6.1 libsodium18 libsoxr0 libssh-gcrypt-4 libswresample2 libswscale4 libtwolame0 libva-drm1 libva-x11-1
  libvpx4 libwebp6 libwebpdemux2 libwebpmux2 libx264-148 libx265-95 libzmq5 libzvbi-common libzvbi0 python3-cffi-backend python3-idna python3-pyasn1 python3.5-dev
Les paquets suivants seront mis à jour :
  jackd2 libav-tools libjack-jackd2-0 libpython3-dev libpython3-stdlib python3
6 mis à jour, 46 nouvellement installés, 8 à enlever et 432 non mis à jour.
144 partiellement installés ou enlevés.
Il est nécessaire de prendre 0 o/53,0 Mo dans les archives.
Après cette opération, 68,0 Mo d'espace disque seront libérés.
Souhaitez-vous continuer ? [O/n] O
Lecture des fichiers de modifications (« changelog »)... Terminé
Extraction des modèles depuis les paquets : 100%
Préconfiguration des paquets...
Paramétrage de python3.5-minimal (3.5.3-1+deb9u5) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/py_compile.py", line 6, in <module>
    import importlib._bootstrap_external
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    import types
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/types.py", line 166, in <module>
    import functools as _functools
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/functools.py", line 23, in <module>
    from weakref import WeakKeyDictionary
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/weakref.py", line 12, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name '_remove_dead_weakref'
dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet python3.5-minimal (--configure) :
 le sous-processus script post-installation installé a retourné une erreur de sortie d'état 1
dpkg: des problèmes de dépendances empêchent la configuration de python3-minimal :
 python3-minimal dépend de python3.5-minimal (>= 3.5.3-1~) ; cependant :
 Le paquet python3.5-minimal n'est pas encore configuré.

dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet python3-minimal (--configure) :
 problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré
Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
 python3.5-minimal
 python3-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

## Configure Python3.5-minimal

So I tried configuring python3.5-minimal which seems to cause the trouble and still get the same error :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo dpkg --configure python3.5-minimal
Paramétrage de python3.5-minimal (3.5.3-1+deb9u5) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/py_compile.py", line 6, in <module>
    import importlib._bootstrap_external
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    import types
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/types.py", line 166, in <module>
    import functools as _functools
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/functools.py", line 23, in <module>
    from weakref import WeakKeyDictionary
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/weakref.py", line 12, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name '_remove_dead_weakref'
dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet python3.5-minimal (--configure) :
 le sous-processus script post-installation installé a retourné une erreur de sortie d'état 1
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour mime-support (3.60) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour desktop-file-utils (0.23-1) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour gnome-icon-theme (3.12.0-1) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u4) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour gnome-menus (3.13.3-9) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-1) ...
Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
 python3.5-minimal
```

Here is my Raspbian version :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.13 (n/a)
Release:        9.13
Codename:       n/a
```

## Edit (1) :

So I tried removing the package which gives me an issue (python3.5-minimal). But I faced manually removing python3 (which is heavily integrated with the system).

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo dpkg --remove python3.5-minimal
dpkg: un problème de dépendance empêche la suppression de python3.5-minimal :
 python3-minimal dépend de python3.5-minimal (>= 3.5.3-1~).
 python3.5 dépend de python3.5-minimal (= 3.5.3-1+deb9u5).

dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet python3.5-minimal (--remove) :
 problème de dépendance - suppression ignorée
Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
 python3.5-minimal
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo dpkg --remove python3.5
dpkg: un problème de dépendance empêche la suppression de python3.5 :
 python3-uno dépend de python3.5 ; cependant :
  Le paquet python3.5 doit être supprimé.
 python3-numpy dépend de python3.5:any ; cependant :
  Le paquet python3.5 doit être supprimé.

dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet python3.5 (--remove) :
 problème de dépendance - suppression ignorée
Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
 python3.5
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo dpkg --remove python3-uno
dpkg: un problème de dépendance empêche la suppression de python3-uno :
 libreoffice dépend de python3-uno (>= 4.4.0~beta2) ; cependant :
  Le paquet python3-uno doit être supprimé.

dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet python3-uno (--remove) :
 problème de dépendance - suppression ignorée
Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
 python3-uno
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo dpkg --remove libreoffice
(Lecture de la base de données... 151036 fichiers et répertoires déjà installés.)
Suppression de libreoffice (1:5.2.7-1+rpi1+deb9u11) ...
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo dpkg --remove python3-uno
(Lecture de la base de données... 151029 fichiers et répertoires déjà installés.)
Suppression de python3-uno (1:5.2.7-1+rpi1+deb9u11) ...
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo dpkg --remove python3-numpy
dpkg: un problème de dépendance empêche la suppression de python3-numpy :
 python3-sense-hat dépend de python3-numpy.
 python3-picamera dépend de python3-numpy.
 python3-sense-emu dépend de python3-numpy.

dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet python3-numpy (--remove) :
 problème de dépendance - suppression ignorée
Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
 python3-numpy
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo dpkg --remove python3-sense-hat
dpkg: un problème de dépendance empêche la suppression de python3-sense-hat :
 sense-hat dépend de python3-sense-hat.

dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet python3-sense-hat (--remove) :
 problème de dépendance - suppression ignorée
Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
 python3-sense-hat
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo dpkg --remove sense-hat
(Lecture de la base de données... 150972 fichiers et répertoires déjà installés.)
Suppression de sense-hat (1.2) ...
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo dpkg --remove python3-sense-hat
(Lecture de la base de données... 150941 fichiers et répertoires déjà installés.)
Suppression de python3-sense-hat (2.2.0-1) ...
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo dpkg --remove python3-picamera
(Lecture de la base de données... 150995 fichiers et répertoires déjà installés.)
Suppression de python3-picamera (1.13) ...
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo dpkg --remove python3-sense-emu
dpkg: un problème de dépendance empêche la suppression de python3-sense-emu :
 sense-emu-tools dépend de python3-sense-emu (>= 1.0).

dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet python3-sense-emu (--remove) :
 problème de dépendance - suppression ignorée
Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
 python3-sense-emu
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo dpkg --remove sense-emu-tools
(Lecture de la base de données... 150926 fichiers et répertoires déjà installés.)
Suppression de sense-emu-tools (1.0) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour gnome-menus (3.13.3-9) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour desktop-file-utils (0.23-1) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour mime-support (3.60) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour libglib2.0-0:armhf (2.50.3-2+deb9u2) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-1) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo dpkg --remove python3-sense-emu
(Lecture de la base de données... 150905 fichiers et répertoires déjà installés.)
Suppression de python3-sense-emu (1.0) ...
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo dpkg --remove python3-numpy
(Lecture de la base de données... 150850 fichiers et répertoires déjà installés.)
Suppression de python3-numpy (1:1.12.1-3) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo dpkg --remove python3.5
(Lecture de la base de données... 150469 fichiers et répertoires déjà installés.)
Suppression de python3.5 (3.5.3-1+deb9u5) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour gnome-menus (3.13.3-9) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour desktop-file-utils (0.23-1) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour mime-support (3.60) ...
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo dpkg --remove python3-minimal
dpkg: un problème de dépendance empêche la suppression de python3-minimal :
 python3 dépend de python3-minimal (= 3.4.2-2).

dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet python3-minimal (--remove) :
 problème de dépendance - suppression ignorée
Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
 python3-minimal
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo dpkg --remove python3
dpkg: un problème de dépendance empêche la suppression de python3 :
 software-properties-common dépend de python3 (>= 3.2.3-3~).
 python3-pyinotify dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
 python3-debian dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
 python3-itsdangerous dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
 dh-python dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
 python3-setuptools dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
 python3-pifacedigital-scratch-handler dépend de python3 (>= 3.2).
 python3-tk:armhf dépend de python3 (>= 3.5).
 python3-tk:armhf dépend de python3 (<< 3.6).
 python3-tk:armhf dépend de python3 (>= 3.5).
 python3-tk:armhf dépend de python3 (<< 3.6).
 gnome-menus dépend de python3:any (>= 3.1~).
 python3-cffi dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) ; cependant :
  Le paquet python3 doit être supprimé.
 python3-ply dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
 python3-urllib3 dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
 python3-software-properties dépend de python3 (>= 3.2.3-3~).
 python3-openssl dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) ; cependant :
  Le paquet python3 doit être supprimé.
 python3-pycparser dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) ; cependant :
  Le paquet python3 doit être supprimé.
 python3-requests dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
 idle3 dépend de python3 (>= 3.5.3-1).
 unattended-upgrades dépend de python3.
 python3-pip dépend de python3.
 python3-pip dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
 python3-pip dépend de python3.
 python3-pip dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
 python3-html5lib dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
 python3-jinja2 dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~) ; cependant :
  Le paquet python3 doit être supprimé.
 python3-chardet dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
 python3-pifacecommon dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
 python3-minecraftpi dépend de python3 (>= 3.2.3-3~).
 python3-distlib dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
 python3-pifacedigitalio dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
 python3-markupsafe dépend de python3 (<< 3.6).
 python3-markupsafe dépend de python3 (>= 3.5~).
 python3-markupsafe dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
 python3-markupsafe dépend de python3 (<< 3.6).
 python3-markupsafe dépend de python3 (>= 3.5~).
 python3-markupsafe dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
 python3-markupsafe dépend de python3 (<< 3.6).
 python3-markupsafe dépend de python3 (>= 3.5~).
 python3-markupsafe dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
 python3-gi dépend de python3 (<< 3.6).
 python3-gi dépend de python3 (>= 3.5~).
 python3-gi dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
 python3-gi dépend de python3 (<< 3.6).
 python3-gi dépend de python3 (>= 3.5~).
 python3-gi dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
 python3-gi dépend de python3 (<< 3.6).
 python3-gi dépend de python3 (>= 3.5~).
 python3-gi dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
 python3-pkg-resources dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
 python3-twython dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
 python3-wheel dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
 python3-wheel dépend de python3.
 python3-wheel dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
 python3-wheel dépend de python3.
 gdebi-core dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
 python3-dev dépend de python3 (= 3.5.3-1).
 python3-colorama dépend de python3:any (>= 3.4~).
 python3-six dépend de python3:any (>= 3.4~).
 python3-pigpio dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
 python3-serial dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
 python3-serial dépend de python3.
 python3-serial dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
 python3-serial dépend de python3.
 python3-picraft dépend de python3 (>= 3.2.3-3~).
 python3-dbus dépend de python3 (<< 3.6).
 python3-dbus dépend de python3 (>= 3.5~).
 python3-dbus dépend de python3 (<< 3.6).
 python3-dbus dépend de python3 (>= 3.5~).
 python3-apt dépend de python3 (<< 3.6).
 python3-apt dépend de python3 (>= 3.5~).
 python3-apt dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
 python3-apt dépend de python3 (<< 3.6).
 python3-apt dépend de python3 (>= 3.5~).
 python3-apt dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
 python3-apt dépend de python3 (<< 3.6).
 python3-apt dépend de python3 (>= 3.5~).
 python3-apt dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
 python3-flask dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
 python3-pil:armhf dépend de python3 (<< 3.6).
 python3-pil:armhf dépend de python3 (>= 3.5~).
 python3-pil:armhf dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
 python3-pil:armhf dépend de python3 (<< 3.6).
 python3-pil:armhf dépend de python3 (>= 3.5~).
 python3-pil:armhf dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
 python3-pil:armhf dépend de python3 (<< 3.6).
 python3-pil:armhf dépend de python3 (>= 3.5~).
 python3-pil:armhf dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
 python3-codebug-tether dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
 python3-gpiozero dépend de python3 (>= 3.2.3-3~).
 python3-codebug-i2c-tether dépend de python3 (>= 3.2.3-3~).
 python3-werkzeug dépend de python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~).
 python3-cryptography dépend de python3 (>= 3~).
 python3-cryptography dépend de python3:any (>= 3.4~) ; cependant :
  Le paquet python3 doit être supprimé.
 python3-cryptography dépend de python3 (>= 3~).
 python3-cryptography dépend de python3:any (>= 3.4~) ; cependant :
  Le paquet python3 doit être supprimé.

dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet python3 (--remove) :
 problème de dépendance - suppression ignorée
Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
 python3
```

So once I removed all those packages, I tried to upgrade python3 with the --fix-broken option.

And once again I faced the following error (even if a few packages installed successfully) :

```
Dépaquetage de python3.5 (3.5.3-1+deb9u5) ...
Paramétrage de python3.5-minimal (3.5.3-1+deb9u5) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/py_compile.py", line 6, in <module>
    import importlib._bootstrap_external
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    import types
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/types.py", line 166, in <module>
    import functools as _functools
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/functools.py", line 23, in <module>
    from weakref import WeakKeyDictionary
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/weakref.py", line 12, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name '_remove_dead_weakref'
dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet python3.5-minimal (--configure) :
 le sous-processus script post-installation installé a retourné une erreur de sortie d'état 1
dpkg: des problèmes de dépendances empêchent la configuration de python3-minimal :
 python3-minimal dépend de python3.5-minimal (>= 3.5.3-1~) ; cependant :
 Le paquet python3.5-minimal n'est pas encore configuré.
```

## Edit (2) :

I tried removing python3 with following command and then tried fixing :

```
sudo dpkg -r --force-depends python3
sudo apt-get install -f
```

But still get the following error :

```
Setting up python3.5-minimal (3.5.3-1+deb9u5) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/py_compile.py", line 6, in <module>
    import importlib._bootstrap_external
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    import types
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/types.py", line 166, in <module>
    import functools as _functools
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/functools.py", line 23, in <module>
    from weakref import WeakKeyDictionary
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/weakref.py", line 12, in <module>
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name '_remove_dead_weakref'
dpkg: error processing package python3.5-minimal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-minimal:
 python3-minimal depends on python3.5-minimal (>= 3.5.3-1~); however:
  Package python3.5-minimal is not configured yet.
```

## Edit (3) :

So I tried removing all python packages (yes a little brutal), and the same error still happens.

```
dpkg --list | grep python | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | xargs -n1 sudo dpkg -r --force-depends
dpkg --list | grep python | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | xargs -n1 sudo dpkg -r --force-depends
dpkg --list | grep python | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | xargs -n1 sudo dpkg -P --force-depends
```

By the way, I think there's still some python3 idk how to get rid of it.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3
Python 3.9.0 (default, Nov  6 2020, 10:32:15)
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ dpkg --list | grep python
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Comment: Are you sure that the -f flag is the same as --fix-broken ? 
There is no -f mentioned in the manpage

Comment: Yes I've done the same operation with --fix-broken and it behaves the same way. By the way, there is a mention of `-f, --fix-broken` option in man of `apt-get`

Comment: Looks like a botched dist upgrade *from jessie* (providing python3 3.4.2-2) to stretch. You should give more context about what was done in the past to fix what is intended for the future. When was the upgrade from jessie to stretch attempted? How was it done? what are the sources.list contents? additional repositories etc. etc. Also output of `apt-cache policy python3`?

Comment: @A.B The upgrade was done through apt-get dist-upgrade. Simply modified the sources.list content by editing jessie to stretch. deb-src is also activated.
Here is my apt-cache policy for python3 : `python3:
  Installé : 3.4.2-2
  Candidat : 3.5.3-1
 Table de version :
     3.5.3-1 500
        500 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf Packages
 *** 3.4.2-2 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
`

Comment: I can just tell something went wrong during the dist upgrade since you should already have the strech version and not have kept the jessie version. Also doing `export LANG=C.UTF-8` before typing commands will help people read results.

Comment: Is there a way to remove python3 without having to remove each package one by one ? (Which could take a while)

Comment: Can't help, beside telling your question isn't only about python but a problem during the upgrade from jessie. That's often caused when you install separately an other package not provided by Raspberry/Debian that depends on the older version and makes the upgrade fail. But can't tell nor will give an advice that will make your system not working at all anymore

Comment: All I know is that I compiled a few packages while I was on Jessie on my own. I specifically compiled python btw with special modifications on that time, that's why I'm focusing on python, and also since everything i'm trying to do with apt goes back to python3 somehow.

Comment: Btw, Im ready for solutions that might corrupt the system because my other option would be to reinstall the entire system ;)